# asp.net querystring formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string, request-queueing

How can i send special characters in a querystring?

Like:

```
thankyou.aspx?data=GQH/FUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G++VktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw
```

The **++** gets taken out when i do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim theData As String = Request.QueryString("data")
  ....
```

It stores it inside theData like this:

**GQH/FUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G  VktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw**

So therefore its invalid. How can i properly send that string over without it changing once its received?

**update**

Doing this:

```
Dim en As String = endecryption.EncryptData("=" & "aclub" & "=" & strName & "=" & strEmail)
Response.Redirect("/thankyou.aspx?data=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(en), False)
```

And at the other end:

```
Dim theData As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("data"))
```

It sends it like: **GQH%2fFUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G%2bVktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw**

But it decodes it like: **GQH/FUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G[2 spaces here]VktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw**

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856140/encrypt-and-decrypt-password/12856263#12856263

Comment: @Aristos: When i do that it comes out as **GQH%2fFUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G%2b%2bVktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw**

Comment: What you do ? if you make the full replacement and encode/decode then the string is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at using Server.UrlEncode() to encode the param before including it in the querystring, and using Server.UrlDecode() to transform it back when you need it.

[msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

calling Server.UrlEncode() on "GQH/FUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G++VktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw" yields:

```
GQH%2fFUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G%2b%2bVktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw
```

and calling Server.UrlDecode on that result yields:

```
GQH/FUvq9sQbWwrYh5xX7G++VktXU5o17hycAfNSND8gt8YbbUaJbwRw
```

You need to make sure that you url encode the query string data before you append it on the url.

Comment: Seems to still leave out the **++** even when i add those 2 things.

Comment: then you're doing something wrong. you need to url encode the query string data before you add it to the url and redirect the user to that url. when you get the data out, you just Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("data")) to get the result as plain text.

Comment: I'm doing **Dim theData As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("data"))** and its not converting for some reason? It just has the spaces where the **++** would be going.

Comment: and are you encoding the querystring that you stick on the url before the user hits the page?

Comment: hmm, did you update the OP with the data exactly as you get it? the encoded string as you posted it only shows one %2b where you say two spaces are showing up, which is... weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. <strike>As Mike stated, you can [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) the base64 string above (and conversely decode)</strike>
2. If you're sticking with MS on both ends, you can also look into [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx) - see [this note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789179/304683) if you choose this option

### Update

Ugh. It's coming back to me - base64 gotchas: *"The constructor for HttpRequest will parse the actual string QueryString and UrlDecode the values for you.  Be careful not to DOUBLE DECODE."* - [**Scott Hanselman**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx)

My personal suggestion would be to go the UrlToken route if you're going to do base64...

Comment: MD5 then converted to base64? How are you converting the md5 hash to a string?